C# Image to ASCII converter
I'm trying to learn C# this summer and would like some feedback and criticism on some code I've written. Be as nit-picky as you like.
using ImageMagick;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading Image ....");
        string imageFileName = "chitanda.jpg";
        // Read from file.
        using (var imageFromFile = new MagickImage(imageFileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Image Loaded!");
            
            var height = imageFromFile.Height;
            var width = imageFromFile.Width;

            Console.WriteLine($"Image is {height}x{width}");

            // pixel array
            var pixels = imageFromFile.GetPixels();

            var imgInfo = new MagickImageInfo(imageFileName);
            // convert to brightness array

            // change the text color in the terminal
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

            var brightness = brightnessArray(pixels, imgInfo);
            for (var j = 0; j < brightness.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < brightness.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(brightnessToAscii(brightness[i, j]));
                    Console.Write(brightnessToAscii(brightness[i, j]));
                    Console.Write(brightnessToAscii(brightness[i, j]));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


            Console.WriteLine($"Depth: {imageFromFile.Depth} bits/channel");

        }
    }

    public static void printPixels(IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(var pixel in pixels) 
        {
            var pixelValues = pixel.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine($"Red: {pixelValues[0]}, Green: {pixelValues[1]}, Blue: {pixelValues[2]}");

            i++;
        }
    }

    public static int[,] brightnessArray(IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels, MagickImageInfo info)
    {
        int[,] brightness = new int[info.Width, info.Height];
        
        // What Conversion method will we use?
        int method = -1;
        while (method < 1 || method > 3) { 
            Console.WriteLine("What method Would you like to use? Press 1 for Average, 2 for Lightness, or 3 for luminosity: ");
            method = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        // Process the pixels
        foreach (var pixel in pixels)
        {
            var pixelArray = pixel.ToArray();
           
            int brightValue;
            if (method == 1)
            {
                brightValue = (pixelArray[0] + pixelArray[1] + pixelArray[2]) / 3;
            }
            else if (method == 2)
            {
                var rgbMax = new[] { pixelArray[0], pixelArray[1], pixelArray[2] }.Max();
                var rgbMin = new[] { pixelArray[0], pixelArray[1], pixelArray[2] }.Min();
                brightValue = (rgbMax + rgbMin) / 2;
            }
            else 
            {
                brightValue = Convert.ToInt32((pixelArray[0] * 0.21) + (pixelArray[1] * 0.72) + (pixelArray[2] * 0.07));
            }
            
            brightness[pixel.X, pixel.Y] = brightValue;
        }
        return brightness;
    }


    public static char brightnessToAscii(int brightness)
    {
        
        brightness = brightness / 257;
        string asciiChars = "`^\",:;Il!i~+_-?][}{1)(|\\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$";
        int index = brightness * (asciiChars.Length - 1) / 255;

        var invert = true;
        if (invert == true)
        {
            index = invertAscii(index, asciiChars.Length - 1);
        }
        return Convert.ToChar(asciiChars[index]);
    }


    public static int invertAscii(int Ascii, int characterslength)
    {
        return Math.Abs(Ascii - characterslength);
    }


}


Well, let us be nit-picky then.

Every developer has his own preferences when it comes to formatting code. It does not matter what your preferences are; however, they should be applied consistently. Example: empty lines between methods. Sometimes you have one line sometimes two.

Blank lines separate pieces of code and provide a visual indication of what belongs together. They don't add a value after an opening brace or before a closing brace and can be removed. Okay, my personal preference, I agree.

Naming conventions: In C#, the convention prevails that variable and parameter  names are written in camelCase and type names, method names and property names in PascalCase. See also C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions for a more detailed suggestion.

You have an identifier brightnessArray, but it does not denote an array of brightnesses. Instead, it stands for a method converting a pixel collection into an array of brightnesses. A good name would be: PixelsToBrightness (similar to your brightnessToAscii method).

Usage of var. The keyword var very is handy; however, it can make reading the code difficult. Try to choose a good balance between implicitly and explicitly typed declarations. Good rules are:

Always use the explicit type when a C# type alias exists. Example: C# int is an alias for the .NET type System.Int32.
If the type is apparent as in List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(); you can simplify the declaration in two ways:

With var: var persons = new List<Person>();.
With a target typed new: List<Person> persons = new();.
In both cases the declaration gets more concise,  and no information gets lost.


Use an explicit type when the type is not obvious.
Exception: LINQ queries can return very complex nested generic types, which are usually of no interest to anyone, because the result is immediately processed as if it was a IEnumerable<T> or used to query a database. Here you can use var.


Starting with C# 8.0, you can use using declarations to make the code simpler instead of using statements:
using var imageFromFile = new MagickImage(imageFileName);
...

instead of
using (var imageFromFile = new MagickImage(imageFileName)) {
     ...
}


It is perfectly fine to write a condition as method < 1 || method > 3, but pattern matching can make it a bit shorter: method is < 1 or > 3 (you don't have to repeat the variable name).

The usage of compound assignments is another simplification: brightness /= 257; instead of brightness = brightness / 257;.

The string asciiChars in BrightnessToAscii does never change and must never change. Make it a constant. This protects you from inadvertently modifying it and produces a more efficient code.

You have var invert = true; immediately followed by if (invert == true). This flag would make more sense and be more useful as a class constant: private const bool InvertImage = false; (or true). Also, you can simplify the check to: if (InvertImage) (the comparison  == true is superfluous).

By making our local const string AsciiChars a class constant, we can reuse it in InvertAscii and let the method itself determine its length, instead of passing the length as parameter. We are not inverting the Ascii string but an index into this string. Therefore I prefer the name InvertAsciiIndex:
public static int InvertAsciiIndex(int index)
{
     return Math.Abs(index - (AsciiChars.Length - 1));
}


We can get rid of the \ escape characters by using a Raw string literal:
private const string AsciiChars = """`^",:;Il!i~+_-?][}{1)(|\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$""";


Comments can be a valuable source of information, but they can also be an indication that the code is not very readable. Example:
// pixel array
var pixels = imageFromFile.GetPixels();

better:
IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels = imageFromFile.GetPixels();

It turns out, that the designation "array" was not even correct.

Sometimes comments seem redundant because the code speaks for itself:
// change the text color in the terminal
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;


There is a comment // convert to brightness array immediately following a statement but itself followed by an empty line and then the Console.ForegroundColor assignment. Does it apply to the previous line or to the next ones and how many of them? In fact, this applies to the statement after that:
int[,] brightness = PixelsToBrightness(pixels, imgInfo);

Another unnecessary comment (since we changed the method name to be descriptive).

You execute the exact same instruction three times in a row and thus repeat the conversion of a brightness three times. Assign the result of the conversion to a temporary variable:
char character = BrightnessToAscii(brightness[i, j]);
Console.Write(character);
Console.Write(character);
Console.Write(character);


The method we renamed to PixelsToBrightness not only performs a conversion but also prompts the user for a conversion method. We should separate the two concerns and get the input from the user in the Main method instead and pass the result as a parameter to the method.
The comment // Process the pixels will then also become superfluous, because then the method will only do what the method name says.
After applying this refactoring, we can correct the prompt and the user input being dark green instead of only the Ascii output: 1. Prompt the user. 2. Change the text color to dark green. 3. Produce the Ascii output.

Instead of using the magic numbers 1, 2, 3 for the conversion methods, we can use an enum to make the code more readable:
public enum ConversionMethod
{
     Average = 1,
     Lightness = 2,
     Luminosity = 3
}

We can replace the if-else if-else by a switch statement.
Why create a new array new[] { pixelValues[0], pixelValues[1], pixelValues[2] } twice to get the min and max values? pixelValues is already the array we need and we can simply write pixelValues.Min() (or Max()).
The result is a more readable method:
public static int[,] PixelsToBrightness(IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels, MagickImageInfo info, ConversionMethod method)
{
     int[,] brightness = new int[info.Width, info.Height];
     foreach (IPixel<ushort> pixel in pixels) {
         ushort[] pixelValues = pixel.ToArray();

         int brightValue = 0;
         switch (method) {
             case ConversionMethod.Average:
                 brightValue = (pixelValues[0] + pixelValues[1] + pixelValues[2]) / 3;
                 break;
             case ConversionMethod.Lightness:
                 ushort rgbMin = pixelValues.Min();
                 ushort rgbMax = pixelValues.Max();
                 brightValue = (rgbMax + rgbMin) / 2;
                 break;
             case ConversionMethod.Luminosity:
                 brightValue = Convert.ToInt32((pixelValues[0] * 0.21) + (pixelValues[1] * 0.72) + (pixelValues[2] * 0.07));
                 break;
         }

         brightness[pixel.X, pixel.Y] = brightValue;
     }
     return brightness;
}


If you do not intend to use these methods outside of the Program class, you can make all its members private. After I did this, Visual Studio grayed out the method PrintPixels, indicating that it is never called. You probably used it for debugging. Since the pixels are hidden inside a IPixelCollection, they cannot be seen easily in the debugger. Therefore, let us keep this method (and remove the unused variable i). In other cases, you can use debugging techniques of your IDE. See also Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio and Debugging in Visual Studio Code.


The entire revised code:
using ImageMagick;

internal class Program
{
    private const bool InvertImage = false;
    private const string AsciiChars = """`^",:;Il!i~+_-?][}{1)(|\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$""";

    private enum ConversionMethod
    {
        Average = 1,
        Lightness = 2,
        Luminosity = 3
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading Image ....");
        string imageFileName = @"chitanda.jpg";

        // Read image from file.
        using var imageFromFile = new MagickImage(imageFileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Image Loaded!");

        uint height = imageFromFile.Height;
        uint width = imageFromFile.Width;

        Console.WriteLine($"Image is {height}x{width}");

        IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels = imageFromFile.GetPixels();

        var imgInfo = new MagickImageInfo(imageFileName);

        // What conversion method will we use?
        int conversionInput = -1;
        while (conversionInput is < 1 or > 3) {
            Console.WriteLine("What method Would you like to use? Press 1 for Average, 2 for Lightness, or 3 for luminosity: ");
            conversionInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

        int[,] brightness = PixelsToBrightness(pixels, imgInfo, (ConversionMethod)conversionInput);
        for (int j = 0; j < brightness.GetLength(1); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < brightness.GetLength(0); i++) {
                char character = BrightnessToAscii(brightness[i, j]);
                Console.Write(character);
                Console.Write(character);
                Console.Write(character);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Depth: {imageFromFile.Depth} bits/channel");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void PrintPixels(IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels)
    {
        foreach (var pixel in pixels) {
            ushort[] pixelValues = pixel.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine($"Red: {pixelValues[0]}, Green: {pixelValues[1]}, Blue: {pixelValues[2]}");
        }
    }

    private static int[,] PixelsToBrightness(IPixelCollection<ushort> pixels, MagickImageInfo info, ConversionMethod method)
    {
        int[,] brightness = new int[info.Width, info.Height];
        foreach (IPixel<ushort> pixel in pixels) {
            ushort[] pixelValues = pixel.ToArray();

            int brightValue = 0;
            switch (method) {
                case ConversionMethod.Average:
                    brightValue = (pixelValues[0] + pixelValues[1] + pixelValues[2]) / 3;
                    break;
                case ConversionMethod.Lightness:
                    ushort rgbMin = pixelValues.Min();
                    ushort rgbMax = pixelValues.Max();
                    brightValue = (rgbMax + rgbMin) / 2;
                    break;
                case ConversionMethod.Luminosity:
                    brightValue = Convert.ToInt32((pixelValues[0] * 0.21) + (pixelValues[1] * 0.72) + (pixelValues[2] * 0.07));
                    break;
            }
            brightness[pixel.X, pixel.Y] = brightValue;
        }
        return brightness;
    }

    private static char BrightnessToAscii(int brightness)
    {
        brightness /= 257;
        int index = brightness * (AsciiChars.Length - 1) / 255;
        if (InvertImage) {
            index = InvertAsciiIndex(index);
        }
        return Convert.ToChar(AsciiChars[index]);
    }

    private static int InvertAsciiIndex(int index)
    {
        return Math.Abs(index - (AsciiChars.Length - 1));
    }
}

